# EF7/MVC6 How to scope DbContext/Data Layer/Service Layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I was watching this course in pluralsight: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app/table-of-contents

And it showed an example of a standard repository pattern and scoping that in the new configure to per HTTP Request. I know this is because the dbcontext is not thread safe. However, I came up with an alternative that seemed better to me. Something like this:

```
public class POCORepository {
    private MyDbContext Context { get { return DbContextWrapper.GetContext(); }}
}
```

By removing the dbcontext as a member of the repository, and instead writing a wrapper class for your dbcontext, you could then scope your dbcontext/dbcontext wrapper to per HTTP request, but all your services/repositories could then be singletons. Isn't having more singletons more efficient? Would this not work? Are there drawbacks?

Comment: Any update to this? Have you tried it in the real world? How's it working out?

Comment: It works fine. You just do exactly as I said, scope repositories and services to singleton. I'll post an answer.